# feature vector of image using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract the feature vector of the image. I came across this link which seems to do exactly what I need.

Link: https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_101/feature_vector/1

```
def get_2k_descriptor(self, im):

    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(im, tf.float32)

    module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_101/feature_vector/1")
    height, width = hub.get_expected_image_size(module)
    resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 224])
    reshaped_image = tf.reshape(resized_image, [1, 224, 224, 3])
    feature = module(reshaped_image) 
    print(feature)
```

I followed their instructions and have the above method. However, running this code gives me the output as follows:

```
Tensor("module_apply_default/hub_output/feature_vector/SpatialSqueeze:0", shape=(1, 2048), dtype=float32)
```

I know to actually evaluate the value, we need a session. I have been working on this for a while now, but have not been able to figure out what changes are needed to actually compute the value of the feature variable.

Can anyone please advice me regarding this issue?

Comment: Hey I am not sure but I can say that the result you are getting is a tensor
and you can evaluate it by passing it to `session.run()`

Answer (score 0):

The `print(feature)` does not output the actual value of the tensor. To produce the feature vector of the image, you need to run:

```
session.run(feature, feed_dict={image_placeholder: testimage})
```

Upon running this, you can obtain the feature map of the test image